# <PHP> how to generate a unique field without auto-increment

Tags: php

i'm trying to generate a unique id using this code:

**$RCode = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));**

then i want it to check in my database if the RCode is unique.

if it isnt i want it to use that part of the code again and check in my database again if it is unique,

if it is unique it should write to my database.

i have all the code i need for checking and writing into the database, **i just have no idea how to make it loop back to the start.**

Help is appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: md5 and uniqid but you have problems with a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical example for do-while loop.

Some PHP-pseudocode:

```
do {
    $rcode = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    $res = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records WHERE rcode='$rcode'"));
} while ($res[0] > 0);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO records (rcode) VALUES ('$rcode')");
```

Comment: Better just try to `insert` and check for errors. This code might still fail, since another request might insert a record between the `select` and `insert` in this script. Also, it would perform better, because the `insert` will hardly ever fail. You can save a `select` for most every request.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother checking at first. Instead put a unique constraint on the column, that way the insert will fail if the RCode isn't unique. Then you can handle that error/exception and try another hash. The probability of a collision is low so in this case you probably aren't going to be hammering the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
$found = false;
while (! $found) {
  //try..
  if (...unique...) {
    $found = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to the start is as easy as implementing a `while` loop. Heck, you could even use **goto** (kidding!).

But I don't understand why you don't want to use auto_increment.

Comment: i cant use auto increment because of the way this code will be used :)

Comment: I doubt if your judgement in that is valid if you don't know how to set up a while loop. But its your project. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "loop forever then break out on success" method:

```
while (true) {
    $RCode = ...;
    if ($RCode does not exist in db) {
        break;
    }
}
write to the db
```

Edit: Or better, make sure the field has a unique constraint on it, then test for uniqueness by checking for failure of an insert:

```
while (true) {
    $RCode = ...
    try to insert RCode
    if (no failure) {
        break;
    }
}
```

This will be more resilient to concurrent hits.

Answer (score 0):

As you hash `uniqid()` returned value using `md5()` (the same goes for any other hashing algorithm), possibility of getting **not** unique string is extremely low.

In my opinion, its so low that checking for that string to be unique would be overkill.

All you need to do is insert value in the database. It will be unique!

**Edit:**

You should use `uniqid(null, true)` to get 23 chars long, unique string. If that is what you need - unique string.

Comment: That's nonsense. Hashing the id doesn't add uniqueness, but it *can* decrease it. `md5(uniquid())` is never more unique than `uniqueid()`.

Comment: @GolezTrol Agree. Hashing `uniqid()` (not `uniqueid()`) is kinda weird. But it will be unique. Not for 100%, but for 99,9% for sure.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't md5 `uniqueid`. `uniqueid` is good enough and it does not have the overhead of `md5` if used by itself.

Second, you are far better off [obscuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506989/encode-and-decode-url-message-id-using-php#6507166) an automatically incrementing number than using a UUID or some equivalent.

But, if you must:

```
do {
    $rcode = uniqid(rand(), true);
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records WHERE rcode='$rcode'");
} while ($res && mysql_num_rows($res));

mysql_query("INSERT INTO records (rcode) VALUES ('$rcode')");

// OR!
// assuming unique index on rcode
do {
    $rcode = uniqid(rand(), true);
} while (mysql_query("INSERT INTO records (rcode) VALUES ('$rcode')"););
```

Comment: You'd better insert the record and check the affected rows. It will save a select and make the code even more solid. Your 'First' and 'Seconds are good points, though.

Comment: @GolezTrol Actually, if there is a unique index, you can skip the count query altogether. Kudos for pointing out that this is a better direction.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a little different to what you asked but it solves the problem of a unique ID in a different way that may be better to use depending on your application.

To be honest I like to use variables such as date and time combined with another variable such as an IP address for this type of thing, you can then be very certain that your ID will be unique because the date and time will not reoccur and in the event there are 2 requests in the same second the IP address of the user is completely unique at this time also. Plus no having to check with the database. An example would be

```
$idstring = date('Ymdhis');
$ipstring = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];
$hashme = $idstring.$ipstring;
$idhash = md5($hashme);
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Yes it does but the way I understand it, uniqueid doesn't use the date meaning the ID can be re-used each day, adding the date means the ID can only be used once. So if you want to use uniqueid and be 100% certain put the date into the string prior to the hash.

Comment: Actually, it does include the date. A timestamp is the number of seconds elapsed since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970, not counting leap seconds.

Comment: That isn't actually specified in the PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Looking at it, the microtime PHP docs do specify it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Answer (score 0):

you can just run MD5 on the timestamp...

```
$uniqueid = md5(time());
```

Comment: but if i get more than 1 request at exact the same time it wont be unique anymore?

Comment: Yea, I realized that after. It's highly unlikely but possible i guess. You can concatenate it with the persons IP Address like in the above post and that should solve the problem.